# Issue to resize element content properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

The text of second `h5` element doesnt resize properly and get out over the background color, I also tested put the `h5` inside a `div` and apply css to the `div` but it didnt work, what am I missing?
Here is the relevant code (I had to remove other elements and css properties):

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.card .front {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
}
.card .front h5 {
    background-color: #5E92F2;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    margin-top: 98%;
    width: 198px;
    height: 44px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front" style="background-image: url('image.jpg');">
                    <h5>Image 1</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="back">Abc</div>
            </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front" style="background-image: url('image.jpg');">
                    <h5>Image 1 With more text</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="back">Abc</div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why have you set a width/height on the h5

Comment: I need a specfific width/height permanent to put the h5 inside the background color

Comment: You could use min-height if you want to allow for more text:  min-height: 44px;

Comment: May I ask, are you expecting the text itself to resize (font getting smaller) when it doesn't fit in the element? ... If yes, then there is no CSS that can do that, for that you need script.

Comment: @LGSon Yes I expect that, and thanks for your explanation in Rahele answer.

Comment: @LGSon But using bootstrap it should resize automatic to fit the text inside the background color right? I missing something

Comment: If they have a script that does, then yes, if not, then no, as CSS can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
h5{
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Nice thank you, could you put any explanation about why this does it work?  I dont understand why.

Comment: @SilverSurfer When using percentage for `font-size`, it use the elements parent's font size, which in your case is a `div`. Compared to what the `h5` have as default, the text now in both your _buttons_ got smaller, and that is all what it does, hence text simply fit. If you add more text, you get the same issue again, with the overflow. If your text can overflow, I suggest you use my answer's solution.

Answer (score 2):

As the `h5` has a fixed height, that is the expected behavior.

Change to `min-height: 44px;` in the `.card .front h5` rule

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.card .front {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
}
.card .front h5 {
    background-color: #5E92F2;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    margin-top: 98%;
    width: 198px;
    min-height: 44px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front" style="background-image: url('image.jpg');">
                    <h5>Image 1</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="back">Abc</div>
            </div>
</section>

<section class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front" style="background-image: url('image.jpg');">
                    <h5>Image 1 With more text</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="back">Abc</div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

For `h5` you are adding `height: 44px;` so the font-size is taking default `h5` font size if you decrease the font size it will fix the issue or increase the height of `h5`

so use something like

```
.card .front h5{
 font-size:16px;
}
```

or

```
.card .front h5{
 height:64px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css set heigth of the element to 44px and font-size to 1.25rem, change one of the properties or both, for example heigth to auto if you want to keep font-size, or change font-size to 100% if you want to keep the heigth of the element. There are several ways to do this.